# Is there a way in python to use os.path operations for an OS that is not your current?

Tags: python, operating-system, remote-access

The situation:  I am currently using paramiko to do some fancy sftp stuff and often find myself compiling path names for remote files.  I think that there might be a more intelligent way of doing this.
The question:
Is there a way in python to use os.path operations for an OS that is not your current os?
I would like to ultimatly be able to go remotehost.os.path."some operation"

Answer (score 7):

As the big Note at the top of [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) says:

> Since different operating systems have different path name conventions, there are several versions of this module in the standard library. The os.path module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths. However, you can also import and use the individual modules if you want to manipulate a path that is always in one of the different formats. They all have the same interface:
>
> - posixpath for UNIX-style paths
> - ntpath for Windows paths
> - macpath for old-style MacOS paths
> - os2emxpath for OS/2 EMX paths

Obviously things like `ntpath.lexists` aren't going to work on a POSIX system, but things like `join`, `basename`, etc. will.

If you don't know what format the remote server expects, and don't have any way to figure it out, `posixpath` is usually a safe bet. `sftp`, and Paramiko's similar functionality, will always handle POSIX paths; if you're using an `ssh` shell, `cmd.exe` and many of the command-line tools you'd want to run (including Python scripts) will be able to handle them on Windows, and the same is true for OS/2, and of course old-style Mac doesn't even have a shell you can `ssh` to.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a good look at [`fabric`](http://docs.fabfile.org/).

- it is leveraging `paramiko` for the low-level stuff (transport/ssh/sftp).
- it is a very good alternative for running a `Task`, or automation.
- they are working on [remote execution hooks (open issue)](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/237).

  - `execnet`, `pushy`, `pyro` ... and other parallel processing libs.

Under the hood, `fabric` uses `posixpath.join()`, since [Windows does support `/` as a directory separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#MS-DOS.2FMicrosoft_Windows_style). They had the same problem you did and changed [from `os.path.join` to `posixpath.join()` in this commit](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/commit/dd6c23f607f8e99ab85b9e6f67b65b98f5157447).

Features of `fabric`:

- [file and directory management](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/contrib/files.html#module-fabric.contrib.files)
- [project tools](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/contrib/project.html) (rsync / whole directory upload)
- [tasks !](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/tasks.html) (plain awesome)

Comment: Did you read the last paragraph of my answer? It already says "`posixpath` is usually a safe bet", and goes on to explain why.

Comment: You can edit my answer to add them, or comment on my answer; it's better to have all the info in one place than to have answers that refer to other answers. (If someone just reads my answer without reading yours, they won't see your links.)

Comment: That's kind of my point: Your answer will be a better answer about `fabric` if 60% of the text isn't about a different answer, and my answer will be a better answer about `paramiko`/just plain paths if you edit that 60% into my answer or add it as a comment.

Comment: "Legitimate" isn't even marginally relevant. The goal of this site isn't to get points for answerers, it's to provide useful help to people with questions. Having one good answer is more helpful than having two half answers about the same thing. Having a second answer that provides completely separate information is more helpful than having a second answer that spends more time commenting on the first answer than adding separate information. That's why we have editing and commenting here—you can improve my answer directly instead of mixing comments on my answer into your own.

Comment: @abarnert, I agree with everything you say, hence I edited my answer to cover `fabric` in more details.